# How to kick user from channel in Discord with PHP

Tags: php, discord

I want to remove from my Discord channel the users with expired subscriptions to my site.
Is possible to do that from PHP?
I've found this RES API: https://github.com/restcord/restcord but is not clear how to do that
Maybe

> $client->guild->removeGuildMember($parameters);

But I think that will remove the user from the server, and I need a list of all user emails (and user ids) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can access a user's email using Restcord or in general, but to get all of the users you can use `$client->guild->listGuildMembers($parameters);` and store it in an array for later use.

But in terms of your issue, you can create a role which doesn't have access to that specific channel(s) and have users subscribe to your site using their emails and discord names + their identifier (i.e. the 4 numbers at the end of their name).

Now, this part of the answer is assuming that you are storing the users' emails and discord names in a database; loop through the array which you stored the guildMembers in originally and check for users who aren't subscribed. If they aren't subscribed remove the role which gives them access to that specific channel(s).

Here's an example:

```
$user_array = $client->guild->listGuildMembers($parameters);

$host= "localhost";
$uid= "root";
$psw= "";
$db= "exampleDB";
try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $uid, $psw);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM subscribers"); 
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
               if(!in_array($row['discord_name'], $user_array){
                          $client->guild->removeGuildMemberRole($guildId, $row['id'], $roleId);
                }
        }
}
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
         echo "Failed to connect";
}
$conn = null
```

Enrique brought up a good point which was that discord names can be changed, so to counter that we will loop through the member list array and find member names which are identical to the one which subscribed, then get that member's id and store it in the subscription database.

Here's an example:

```
$host= "localhost";
$uid= "root";
$psw= "";
$db= "exampleDB";
$username;
$id;
if(isset($_POST['subscribe'])){
      $username = $_POST['discord_name'];
      foreach($user_list as $user){
          if($user->name == $username){
               $id = $user->id;
          }
       }
try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $uid, $psw);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO subscribers(discord_name, id) VALUES('$username', '$id')");
    $stmt->execute();

}
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
         echo "Failed to connect";
}
$conn = null;
```

I hope this helps, this is only a basic guideline of what you can do the rest is up to you!

Comment: thanks Ameer, I like the idea of managing this with roles, but can you complete the code? I think the most important part for the answer is the # remove member here part. I mean I need a way to assign the role and also an API call to remove the role. Also "discord_name" is a fixed name or something the user can change (like a nickname)? I need a safe way to identify the user (that's why I was thinking in the email)

Comment: For sure, also regarding the discord name, it is something which can be changed, so I'll add a solution for that in my edit.

Comment: I'm testing the code, but "listGuildMembers" is not returning all the users, actually only one, do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: oh I see it has a limit parameter default to "1"